# JQuery .ajax call fails to call Success in app, and calls Success, Error, and Complete in JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

After much searching, (and really I understand, people ask millions of questions about Ajax, and this seems to be like so many of them, but I just can't get any of the solutions posted to work) I have to ask - what is going on here?

I'm trying to create an application which displays all of the SNAP benefit providers in my county and allows users to enter data on food availability at those markets.

I have all of my [data stored on CartoDB](http://cdb.io/XVChAg), and I am using their node.js library to return the data at ["/stores"](http://food-desert-mapper.jhk.me/stores).

I've linted the JSON, and the function calls all three callbacks on JSFiddle instead of none.

I can't understand what is going wrong.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/stores",
    success: function (data, code, jqx) {
        console.log("anything?");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (jqx, err, ex) {
        console.log("no?");
        console.log(err);
    },
    complete: function (jqx, status) {
        console.log("dicks" + status);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: maybe cross domain is the problem, don't do your test on jsfiddle, do it on your test server

Comment: agree with Johnathan.  could be a cross domain issue.  look into using "jsonp" for your datatype and determining whether your remote data source and send a callback method.

Comment: @chrisvillanueva putting JSONP, does not mean that you can do cross domain request. server also  allow CORS support by addign Allow-orgin headers

Comment: @Ravi sure, that's understood.  however, i addressed the issue related to the scope of the op's original issue--which is related to javascript, jquery and ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. First, there was/is a bug in Firebug which was preventing console.log to print at all, so that may have been the entire problem. From now on I test with alert.

Second, it is also possible, though I have not verified, that I was also getting problems from using a deprecated form of the ajax command in Jquery 1.9.2. Could be wrong about this. Their documentation was not particularly clear.